# <p></p> creates an unnecessary space in content?

Tags: html

So by default Wordpress include `<p></p>` into the content.

My view source output:

```
<td class="ccontent">  
<p>I would suggest choosing an easier method,<br />
This one is pretty difficult one.</p>
<p>Just a thought.</p>
</td>
```

On my website:

[image]

As you can see there's a weird space at the bottom.

When I include `<?php the_title();?>` it aligns great.

But when I include `<?php the_content();?>` the space appears.

I did an experiment and removed the `<p>` from the content (using function filter).

Then it aligns great, but the content shows in a single line (which I don't want).

So I figured that `<p></p>` is causing this problem.

Is there any way to fix this?

Desperatly need help.

**UPDATE:** Solved by removing some

code from my template style css file. Thanks for the hint, Joe!

Comment: It looks like the site's styles have a large bottom margin on paragraph tags. If you have access to the theme's stylesheet (in a safe way) you could remove the margin-bottom on any p that appears inside a td. But a better solution is to not put your content inside a table unless it's tabular data that should live in a table. You could also prevent p tags from being generated in the content editor, but that would be a site-wide change: https://templ.io/blog/prevent-wordpress-from-adding-p-tags-in-content/

Comment: Brilliant! Fixed the problem! I didn't even thought of looking at the template style css file. Thanks a ton!